# How to output json prettry formt as html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

> I want to output the final result in HTML code.
>
> Input : JSON
> Output :HTML(json pretty formatted)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `pre` element and `JSON.stringify(obj,null, ‘\t’)`